# How are second order nonlinear ordinary differential equations solved?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I conceived the following second order nonlinear ordinary differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}=\frac{k}{(y(x))^2}$$

I can tell it's nonlinear because of the $\frac{k}{(y(x))^2}$ term and second order because of the second order derivative.

Also, I did some research and concluded that it is of the type "missing *x*". In this category we use the relation, [according to SOS math](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/nonlineareq/nonlineareq.html) :  $$\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}=v\frac{dv}{dy} (1)$$  by making *v* equal to $$\frac{dy(x)}{dx} (2)$$ and then, using the chain rule, simplify to obtain equation (1). 
Despite all that, I can't seem to find a logical solution to my ODE. I would appreciate any help or clue! Thanks!

Comment: "Missing $x$" is called: *autonomous differential equation*.

Comment: Are you sure sure the ODE in question is of that type?

Comment: ?? Trivially so, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=v\frac{dv}{dy}$, so substitute that into your equation and you get $$v\frac{dv}{dy}=\frac{k}{y^2}.$$Now, $$v\ dv=\frac{k}{y^2}dy$$ $$-\frac{k}{y}+C_1=\frac{v^2}{2}$$ $$-\frac{2k}{y}+C_2=v^2$$ $$v=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{2k}{y}+C_2}$$Then, integrate and you get$$y = \pm\left(\sqrt{C_2-\dfrac{2k}{y}}y+\dfrac{k\ln\left(\frac{\left|\sqrt{C_2-\frac{2k}{y}}-\sqrt{C_2}\right|}{\sqrt{C_2-\frac{2k}{y}}+\sqrt{C_2}}\right)}{\sqrt{C_2}}\right)+C_3.$$Haven't checked yet, though... (Link [here](http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sqrt%28-2k%2Fy%2Bc%29&intvar=y) to the complicated integral, and click the "Go!" button.)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, if your equation has a second derivative and a zeroth derivative but no first derivative, you can reduce the order by multiplying both sides by the first derivative and integrating. This works mathematically because the $y''$ gives you the "du" you need to integrate the left side, while the $y'$ gives you the "du" you need to integrate the right side. In many physical situations, this amounts to identifying a conservation law.

In this case you wind up with:

$$\frac{1}{2} y'^2=-\frac{k}{y}+C.$$

This equation is separable, provided you can unambiguously choose a sign for the square root.

Comment: What is your source? And where can I find it (if there is one)?

Comment: @Investor Sorry to say that this wasn't taught in my elementary ODEs class, and I didn't have a book in the class where I did learn it. However, this is a standard technique in physics: $my''=f(y)$ so $my''y'=f(y)y'$ so $\frac{1}{2}y'^2-F(y)$ is constant. Thus you have identified the kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2} y'^2$ and the potential energy $-F(y)$ and demonstrated that the total energy is conserved. This works more generally in higher dimensions if you replace $f(y)$ with $\nabla F(y)$.