# How to solve $\ddot{f}=f^{-2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am facing a question where I need to find the solution for this differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}f(t)=\frac{1}{f(t)^2}$$

What type of differential equation is this? What is the standard method for solving it?

Comment: This is a second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation.

Comment: multiply both sides by $\dot{f}$, integrate to turn it into a 1st order non-linear ODE.

Comment: Why not apply Bernoulli's Method?

Comment: I apologise for the mess up, I hope this helps : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726144/h0w-are-second-order-nonlinear-ordinary-differential-equations-solved

Comment: Thanks for help everyone. I think I did find a solution using @achillehui 's suggestion, it is (-9/2)^(1/3)*t^(2/3). Can be checked here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/llxa4izoqo. Will write an answer to this unless I discover I have done something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

We want to solve $f''=f^{-2}$. To that end, we multiply both sides by $f'$:

$$f''f'=f^{-2}f'\implies \frac{df'}{dx}f'=f^{-2}\frac{df}{dx}$$

So if we integrate with respect to $x$ and simplify the differentials:

\begin{align*}
\int f'df'&=\int f^{-2}df\\
(f')^2&=-f^{-1}+C_1\\
f'&=\pm\sqrt{C_1-f^{-1}}\\
\int\frac{df}{\sqrt{C_1-f^{-1}}}&=\pm\int dx
\end{align*}
Using [our good friend WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%201%2Fsqrt%28C-1%2Fx%29) we can simplify the left-hand integral:
$$C_1^{-\frac32}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{C_1-f^{-1}}}{\sqrt{C_1}}\right)+C_1^{-1}f\sqrt{C_1-f^{-1}}=C_2\pm x$$
Where $f^{-1}$ denotes $\frac1{f(x)}$ and not the inverse of the function $f$. This is an implicit description of $f$, but I think it's the best we can do.

Comment: Isn't the description I mentioned in the comments of the Q better? or what am I getting wrong about that?

Comment: @zabop it definitely is, if you're just looking for one solution. And there are (assuming I've done this correctly) constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ which give your solution. But yours is definitely a more compact solution. However, if you want all of the solutions, you have to use this ugly monstrosity.

Comment: Thanks. Will check where I have lost solutions then.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the equation
$$y''(t)=\frac 1{[y(t)]^2}$$ as
$$-\frac {t''(y)}{[t'(y)]^3}=\frac 1 {y^2}$$ Reduction of order $p=t'(y)$
$$\frac {p'}{p^3}=-\frac 1 {y^2}\implies -\frac 1{2p^2}=\frac 1 y+C\implies p=\pm\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{-C y-1}}$$ which is quite nasty but ... doable.